# Could not start test automation - xcodebuild exited with code '0' and signal 'null'

Tags: ios, appium

I have a problem with running automation tests on iOS platform.
Here is an error I get i logs. Will be very grateful for any solution.

Here is a error.

```
debug] [XCUITest] Waiting for WebDriverAgent server to finish    loading...
[debug] [WebDriverAgent] Device: Nov  7 10:44:00 iPhone5cGreen     XCTRunner[226] <Notice>: Running tests...
[debug] [XCUITest] Waiting for WebDriverAgent server to finish   loading...
[Xcode] 2016-11-07 10:44:02.389 xcodebuild[4398:148129] Error     Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Early unexpected     exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be     attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit,    operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}

[Xcode] 
Testing failed:

[Xcode]     Test target WebDriverAgentRunner encountered an error     (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no   restart will be attempted)
** TEST FAILED **


[XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '0' and signal 'null'
```

Comment: i think reinstall appium properly work for this case

Comment: Yes it solved the problem ;)